# Add a new column in a dataframe with the number of days between a start and end timestamp

Tags: r

Having a dataframe with a starting and ending timestamp like this:

```
df <- data.frame(start = c("2016-09-30 00:00:00", "2016-09-30 00:00:00", "2016-09-30 00:00:00"),  end = c("2017-03-12 00:00:00", "2017-06-30 00:00:00", "2017-12-01 00:00:00"))
```

How is it possible to add a new column which shows the duration in days between the start and end point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `difftime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), ymd_hms),
         diff = as.numeric(difftime(end, start, units = 'days')))
```

```
#       start        end diff
#1 2016-09-30 2017-03-12  163
#2 2016-09-30 2017-06-30  273
#3 2016-09-30 2017-12-01  427
```

Answer (score 2):

We could create an interval object with `%--%`

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(span = start %--% end) %>% 
  mutate(difference = as.numeric(span, unit = 'day'), .keep ="unused")
```

Output:

```
                start                 end difference
1 2016-09-30 00:00:00 2017-03-12 00:00:00        163
2 2016-09-30 00:00:00 2017-06-30 00:00:00        273
3 2016-09-30 00:00:00 2017-12-01 00:00:00        427
```